# How to handle wind issues on terrace garden

Tags: damage, urban-gardening, wind-damage, heat, roof-garden

I have planted some seeds on the pot and kept that on the terrace.

But there's too much wind during the evening time.

I'm not sure how the plants can sustain the wind.

Besides my terrace floor is made of cooling tiles and I'm not sure how the plants can sustain the heat.

Any helpful tips on the wind factor would be great.

So i'm quite novice when it comes to rooftop gardening.

Update:

I'm finding the windspeed to be 12 to 25 kph with gusts upto 40kph depending on the season of the year and temperature ranges from 24 to 36 Celcius as it's only 20km from coast humidity is high.

Comment: Hi Vivo, it would be difficult to suggest anything without pictures of the area, knowing your location and weather, and knowing the approx area of the terrace.

Comment: it's 30 kms from coast in Peninsular india , weather is hot and humid usually. It rains during the monsoon

Comment: Can you advise what plants?  One common solution is to pick plants that are tolerant of your condition, rather then to change the environment to the plant.

Comment: @davidgo - right I'm wondering whether the Cooling tile also known as Reflective tile has any bad impact on the plants ?

Comment: @Vivo - why would it?   If I understand correctly, cooling tiles are simply passive reflectors of heat.  ( I could probably contrive some edge cases where it might be an issue, but for the most part I imagine the only thing it can do is increase the difference between day and night temperatures the plant is exposed to on cloudless nights.

Comment: @davidgo - Since the residence is situated in a warm country , cloudless night should be ok. But I get how cooling tiles work now. I'm feeling better now :)

Comment: @RohitGupta - Approximate area is 1500 sq.ft , I have updated the question with some more details

Comment: Regardless of wind or tiles how easy is it to water the plants?  If you have carry buckets of water that would indicate plants that tolerate dry are required.  If there is a tap on the terrace and a drain where excess water can go that allows more choice.

Comment: There'a water tap nearby